# Insert author into table if he does not exists but always return his ID

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to get this function to only insert the author if the author does not exist in the database.

If the author is already inside the 'authors' table (meaning same first name and same last name) then I want this function to not insert the author BUT I still want it to return the author's ID and I'm not sure how to do this.

Here is my insertAuthor function that inserts the author even if he already exists:

```
public static int insertAuthor(Connection conn, Author author) throws SQLException
{
    ResultSet keys = null;
    int authorId;

    // Insert the new Authors into the authors table
    String sqlInsertAuthor = "INSERT into authors"
            + "(author_firstname, author_lastname)"
            + " VALUES (?, ?)";

    try (PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sqlInsertAuthor, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);)
    {
        statement.setString(1, author.getFirstName());
        statement.setString(2, author.getLastName());

        // Execute and return number of rows affected
        int affectedRows = statement.executeUpdate();

        // The number of affected rows should be equal to 1
        if (affectedRows == 1)
        {
            keys = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
            keys.next();
            authorId = keys.getInt(1);
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        System.err.println("ERROR INSERTING AUTHOR: " + e.getMessage());
        return 0;
    }

    return authorId;
}
```

Comment: You could try a unique key on author_firstname and author_lastname - that should throw an error which would be caught by your catch...

Comment: Wouldn't that throw an error even if a firstname already exists and the lastname does not?

Comment: the unique index will require the combination be unique, not just one of the fields... ie "bob" "smith" is different than "joe" "smith"

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are several ways to do it. 
You can use hibernate and it's 2nd level cache to load all authors and check the first and last name. 
You can set the lastname to be unique - it would raise an error if lastname already exists. 
You can do it manually - Just check if the first and last name already exists (select count where firstname and lastname). If 0 add new row.
Etc. 

If you want the id the last solution would be probably the best: instead of count you could select an in - if there is none, there will be null.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to get what I wanted while I was attempting the select count idea by kamirru.

Here is the working code:

```
public static int insertAuthor(Connection conn, Author author) throws SQLException
{
    ResultSet keys = null;
    int authorId;

    // Insert the new Authors into the authors table
    String sqlInsertAuthor = "INSERT into authors"
            + "(author_firstname, author_lastname)"
            + " VALUES (?, ?)";

    try (PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sqlInsertAuthor, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);)
    {
        // Check if author already exists, if yes return his id
        authorId = authorExists(conn, author.getFirstName(), author.getLastName());

        // If 0 is returned then the author does not exist so insert the author
        if (authorId == 0)
        {
            statement.setString(1, author.getFirstName());
            statement.setString(2, author.getLastName());

            // Execute and return number of rows affected
            int affectedRows = statement.executeUpdate();

            // The number of affected rows should be equal to 1
            if (affectedRows == 1)
            {
                keys = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
                keys.next();
                authorId = keys.getInt(1);
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        System.err.println("ERROR INSERTING AUTHOR: " + e.getMessage());
        return 0;
    }

    return authorId;
}

public static int authorExists(Connection conn, String firstName, String lastName) throws SQLException
{
    int authorId = 0;

    // Select the author to check if he exists
    String sqlCountAuthor = "SELECT author_id"
            + " FROM authors"
            + " WHERE author_firstname = ? AND author_lastname = ?";
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try (PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sqlCountAuthor);)
    {
        statement.setString(1, firstName);
        statement.setString(2, lastName);

        rs = statement.executeQuery();

        // If a result is returned then the author already exists so take his id
        if (rs.next())
        {
            authorId = rs.getInt("author_id");
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        System.err.println("ERROR SELECTING AUTHOR: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        if (rs != null)
        {
            rs.close();
        }
    }

    return authorId;
}
```